# Variable Undefined For Straightforward React Hooks Axios Fetch Demo App

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am writing a straightforward react app with a very basic api (git hub repo: https://github.com/mrarthurwhite/use_effect_react_hooks_demo). Following is the functional component which is a demo component meant to illustrate a fetch (with `axios`), using the `useEffect` hook, followed by just displaying the data.

```
import './App.css';
import React, {  useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function GetWordsWAxiosNLoading() {
  const [words, setWords] = useState([]);
  let isLoading = false;
  let [isLoadings, setIsLoadings] = useState(false); // initially using state variable
  console.log("isLoading prefetch " + isLoading); 

  async function fetchData(){
    //setIsLoading(true);
    isLoading = true;
    console.log("isLoading fetching " + isLoading); 
    let url = 'http://localhost:1111/wordlist';
    const result= await axios(url);
    setWords(result.data);
    //setIsLoading(false);
    isLoading = false;
    console.log("isLoading resetting " + isLoading); 
  };

  useEffect(() => {fetchData()}, [] );
  console.log("isLoading postfetch " + isLoading); 
    return (
    <>
    { isLoading? (<div>Loading . . . </div>) : (     {words.map(w=> <div>{w.word}</div>)}    ) }
    </>
  );
}

export default GetWordsWAxiosNLoading;
```

The error I am getting is :

```
./src/GetWordsWAxiosNLoading.js
SyntaxError: use_effect_react_hooks_demo/use_effect_initial_demo/src/GetWordsWAxiosNLoading.js: Unexpected token (27:59)

  25 |     return (
  26 |     <>
> 27 |     { isLoading? (<div>Loading . . . </div>) : (     {words.map(w=> <div>{w.word}</div>)}    ) }
     |                                                            ^
  28 |     </>
  29 |   );
  30 | }
```

At line 27 above it is giving both a   `Line 27:60:  Parsing error: Unexpected token` & a `SyntaxError`.

I have working variants of the above :

1. where I am just using `fetch` instead of `axios` httpclient (https://github.com/mrarthurwhite/use_effect_react_hooks_demo/blob/master/use_effect_initial_demo/src/App.js), & it works fine but initially it was giving me similar errors (words was undefined & it could not find .map) indicating that the errors returned are stock & perhaps not very descriptive nor accurate.
2. where I am using `axios` but without a loading variable ( https://github.com/mrarthurwhite/use_effect_react_hooks_demo/blob/master/use_effect_initial_demo/src/GetWordsWAxios.js) & it works fine

The issues are:

1. there are no console log outputs (probably because it is not compiling)
2. the `isLoading` variable is `undefined` (I was initially using `isLoadings` a variable stored in the state object but decided to simplify it).

Any ideas as to what could be going on?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful and cognizant of when you're in a section where you're using JSX syntax, and when you're in a section of plain JavaScript expressions (which may include JSX elements).

When writing JSX, you can interpolate JavaScript expressions by enclosing them in `{}`s, eg:

```
<div className={someClassName}
```

or

```
<span>{someText}</span>
```

That's the only time you should be using `{}` as delimiters for interpolation. Here:

```
    <>
    { isLoading? (<div>Loading . . . </div>) : (     {words.map(w=> <div>{w.word}</div>)}    ) }
    </>
```

The first `{` is needed to go from the JSX fragment to a standard JS expression, but in the second part of the conditional, you're not starting from a JSX context, so you shouldn't have `{`. This:

```
: (     {words.map
```

should be

```
: words.map
```

You should also remove the `isLoading` plain variable, and use the `isLoadings` stateful variable instead. To change state in React, call the state setter - you should almost never be reassigning the value of a plain variable.

Cleaning up your code a bit, try:

```
function GetWordsWAxiosNLoading() {
    const [words, setWords] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    async function fetchData() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:1111/wordlist';
        const result = await axios(url);
        setWords(result.data);
        setIsLoading(false);
    }
    useEffect(fetchData, []);
    return isLoading
        ? <div>Loading . . . </div>
        : words.map(w => <div>{w.word}</div>);
}
```

If the `words` array returned by the API always contains at least one item, you could also remove the `isLoading` state entirely and just check `words.length` instead. If 0, it's still loading.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say: I am getting this example from https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data ... see the section on : LOADING INDICATOR WITH REACT HOOKS

The code you gave worked ! thanks...

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you or some of the other kind folk please upvote this and other question since stackoverflow is preventing me from asking questions saying my previous questions were not received well (they were downvoted by some malicious users). Any help would be appreciated , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

isLoading should be state of component

```
function GetWordsWAxiosNLoading() {
  const [words, setWords] = useState([]);
  let [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  async function fetchData() {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const result = await axios("http://localhost:1111/wordlist");
    setWords(result.data);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div>Loading . . . </div>
      ) : (
        words.map((w) => <div>{w.word}</div>)
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default GetWordsWAxiosNLoading;
```

Comment: that is exactly how I had it initially. Re trying it now. I am getting the same error. @Jan

Comment: the nested interpolating brackets (curly brackets { ) were the issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JanThanks for your response. Would you or some of the other kind folk please upvote this and other question since stackoverflow is preventing me from asking questions saying my previous questions were not received well (they were downvoted by some malicious users). Any help would be appreciated , thanks!